# Select all the rows from the second row from a table?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to select all the rows from the second rows of a table, how can I do it?
I tried the following code, but its not working for me in siebel OpenUI platform.

```
$('#s_1_l').find("tr").each(function() {                    
    if($(this).not(":first-child")){
        alert($(this).find("td:eq(2)").text());              
    }
});
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: Huh? All rows from the second row? Do you mean all columns?

Comment: do you men the **cells** from the second **row**? You can't get a row in a row...

Comment: @Joeytje50 well not with *that* attitude =)

Comment: Maybe you mean *"from the second row forward"*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My understanding is that you want to skip the first `<tr>` and select row #2 and after.

You can achieve that with the `nextAll()` method:

**CSS**

```
tr{
    padding:10px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
// find the first <tr> in the table
// select all the following <tr>'s and make them yellow
$('table').find('tr').eq(0).nextAll('tr').css('background-color','yellow');
```

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr><td>1</td></tr> <!-- not selected -->
    <tr><td>2</td></tr> <!-- selected -->
    <tr><td>3</td></tr> <!-- selected -->
    <tr><td>4</td></tr> <!-- selected -->
    <tr><td>5</td></tr> <!-- selected -->
    <tr><td>6</td></tr> <!-- selected -->
    <tr><td>7</td></tr> <!-- selected -->
</table>
```

Comment: You are welcome, please accept my answer as the correct one if it has correctly answered your question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, my good friend :-)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    console.log($('table[id^=#s_1_l] tr').eq(1));
});
```